# install pycuda error ：gcc: error: /EHsc: No such file or directory

Tags: python, gcc, pycuda

I have met an error when i was installing the pycuda,i tried many times but it didnt work,i already have compiled boost,installed the cuda8.0.here is the error traceback and siteconf.py.

```
error trace back:
     running install
        running bdist_egg
        running egg_info
        writing requirements to pycuda.egg-info\requires.txt
        writing pycuda.egg-info\PKG-INFO
        writing top-level names to pycuda.egg-info\top_level.txt
        writing dependency_links to pycuda.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
        reading manifest file 'pycuda.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
        reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
        warning: no files found matching 'doc\source\_static\*.css'
        warning: no files found matching 'doc\source\_templates\*.html'
        warning: no files found matching '*.cpp' under directory 'bpl-subset\bpl_subset\
        boost'
        warning: no files found matching '*.html' under directory 'bpl-subset\bpl_subset
        \boost'
        warning: no files found matching '*.inl' under directory 'bpl-subset\bpl_subset\
        boost'
        warning: no files found matching '*.txt' under directory 'bpl-subset\bpl_subset\
        boost'
        warning: no files found matching '*.h' under directory 'bpl-subset\bpl_subset\li
        bs'
        warning: no files found matching '*.ipp' under directory 'bpl-subset\bpl_subset\
        libs'
        warning: no files found matching '*.pl' under directory 'bpl-subset\bpl_subset\l
        ibs'
        writing manifest file 'pycuda.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
        installing library code to build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
        running install_lib
        running build_py
        running build_ext
        building '_driver' extension
        C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DMS_WIN64 -mdll -O -Wall -DBOOST_PYTHON_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_CURAND=1 -DPYGPU_PACKAGE=pycuda -DBOOST_THREAD_DONT_USE_CHRONO=1 -DPYGPU_PYCUDA=1 -DBOOST_MULTI_INDEX_DISABLE_SERIALIZATION=1 -DBOOST_THREAD_BUILD_DLL=1 -Dboost=pycudaboost -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -Isrc/cpp -Ibpl-subset/bpl_subset "
-IC:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\include" 
-IC:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include 
-IC:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\include -IC:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\PC 
-c src/cpp/cuda.cpp -o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src\cpp\cuda.o /EHsc
gcc: error: /EHsc: No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda2\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1

siteconf.py:
    BOOST_INC_DIR = ['E:\boost_1_63_0']
    BOOST_LIB_DIR = ['E:\\boost_1_63_0\\stage\\lib']
    BOOST_COMPILER = 'gcc43'
    USE_SHIPPED_BOOST = True
    BOOST_PYTHON_LIBNAME = ['libboost_python-vc100-mt-1_63']
    BOOST_THREAD_LIBNAME = ['libboost_thread-vc100-mt-1_63']
    CUDA_TRACE = False
    CUDA_ROOT = 'C:\\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0'
    CUDA_ENABLE_GL = False
    CUDA_ENABLE_CURAND = True
    CUDADRV_LIB_DIR = ['${CUDA_ROOT}/lib', '${CUDA_ROOT}/lib/x64', '${CUDA_ROOT}/lib/stubs', '${CUDA_ROOT}/lib/x64/stubs']
    CUDADRV_LIBNAME = ['cuda']
    CUDART_LIB_DIR = ['${CUDA_ROOT}/lib', '${CUDA_ROOT}/lib/x64', '${CUDA_ROOT}/lib/stubs', '${CUDA_ROOT}/lib/x64/stubs']
    CUDART_LIBNAME = ['cudart']
    CURAND_LIB_DIR = ['${CUDA_ROOT}/lib', '${CUDA_ROOT}/lib/x64', '${CUDA_ROOT}/lib/stubs', '${CUDA_ROOT}/lib/x64/stubs']
    CURAND_LIBNAME = ['curand']
    CXXFLAGS = ['/EHsc']
    LDFLAGS = ['/FORCE']
```

Could you offer me some help? thank you so much.

Comment: Your siteconf.py contains a very strange looking mixture of gcc and msvc syntax. It is doing *exactly* what you are telling it to, but the real question is why you have chosen to tell it to do so. Only you can answer that.

Comment: I removed the CUDA tag for a reason -- this question doesn't have anything to do with CUDA programming *per se*. Why did you re-add it?

Comment: uh, i dont know you removed the tag, I thougt it was me delete it by accident.

Comment: i dont know how to edit the siteconf.py,i copied it from an introduction,could you offer me a correct edition? thank you..

Comment: I delete the tag.. Thank you for reminding me...